# Is there a way I can solve this problem of error in var?

Tags: r

I was trying to calculate the standard deviation of my dataset and I got this error message. Please can someone help me out?

[image]

```
sapply(NData[,2:6], sd)
```

> Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
>       Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
>       Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.

Comment: You have read the data incorrectly. The headers are in first row. Read the data with `header = TRUE`

Comment: > sapply((NData$V5[2:6],header=T), sd)
Error: unexpected ',' in "sapply((NData$V5[2:6],"
> sapply((NData$V5[2:6] header=T), sd)
Error: unexpected symbol in "sapply((NData$V5[2:6] header"                                            it didn't work

Comment: adding `header=TRUE` to the analysis won't work (as you found out).  You have to go back to the *previous step* where you read the data into R.

Comment: Besides setting `header=TRUE` in the function call that you are using to read your data, you should probably also set `row.names=1` since the first column in your data frame appears to be the row indexes.

Comment: Also column 6 is V7 which is not numeric.